# Separating values in a textbox by special character

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, for-loop

I have an `asp.net/vb.net` web app that requires information to be put into a multiline text box. If the user hits enter while in the textbox it drops down to next line, and they can enter more data in. When it tries to go to the database it fails because of the way the data is represented. I need help with looping through the field and getting each value.

This is how the data is represented in the `DataTable`

```
0;0.123;0.234;0.345;...
```

I need each value between the `;` character... so I was thinking something like this?

```
If dbRow.Item("PV").ToString.Contains(";") Then

    For Each symbol As String In DBTable.Rows

        'get data b/w the ';'

     Next

End If
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Edit:

```
If dbRow.Item("PV").ToString.Contains(";") Then

   For Each s As String In dbRow.Item("PV").ToString

       Dim fields() As String = s.Split(";"c)

       For Each value As String In fields

            .Append("'" & CDbl(value) & "'," & "SysDate,1)")
             DBCommand.CommandText = myInsertIntoProperty_DataStringBuilder.ToString
             DBCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
             myInsertIntoPropertyStringBuilder = New StringBuilder

        Next

     Next

    Else

            .Append("'" & CDbl(dbRow.Item("PV")) & "'," & "SysDate,1)")

    End If
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to replace the line breaks with semi-colons and when reading from the database, replace the semi-colons with line breaks?

Comment: Please use Split(';') function  see below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503310/get-the-nth-string-of-text-between-2-separator-characters

Comment: No I don't want to replace them , I just want to get the data in-between the `;` so I want `0,0.123,0.234`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
 Dim s As String In dbRow.Item("PV").ToString()
 Dim fields() As String = s.Split(";"c)

 For Each value As String In fields
     ' Do what you want with the value
 Next
```

Then access each value with `field(0)`, `fields(1)`, etc. You can then convert it to the appropriate type, for example:

```
Dim value As Double = Double.Parse(fields(0), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: The amount of fields would be varying though, would you just run another `forloop` and do whatever with each field?

Comment: I had to change around one thing and it works except each value in the array `fields()` in the `for loop` is showing up as `""`

Comment: Maybe you have empty values in the DataTable (like `;;`). You can use this to remove empty entries: `Dim fields() As String = s.Split(";".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: I just looked at the whole string value and there are no empty entries...I'll update what I have now

Comment: Just remove the `.ToString` at the end in: `For Each s As String In dbRow.Item("PV").ToString`

Comment: Sorry I was coding without trying the code. Try my edit