# Find the data after Nth column delimiters in C#

Tags: c#

I have a file containing rows with pipe (`|`) in column delimiter, I want to find the infomation between the 99th and 100th delimiters.
The row has been read into my string variable such as `string str = @"1|2|a|||....|||abc|d|...."` and I want to find and store the `abc` value in my another variable.

is there any neat way, such as using Regex, to make the solution work? It seems too stupid to loop 100 times using something like `substring`.

Comment: `string.split("|")[99]` not tested but should be close enough

Comment: You can use skip(99)

Comment: You can adapt this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/187394/2956272. Still, the most efficient solution is just a loop with indexof (you can supply a starting position as a parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a regular expression just because you can. It's usually far easier to not use them in most circumstances.

Instead you should use the built in operators and do something like:

```
str.split("|")[99];
```

*Not tested but should be close enough for you to get what you want*

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.Split` to split the string into an array and then access it via index:

```
var arr = str.Split('|');
var yourOtherVariable = arr[99];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below method also, logic is to get the substring from start position of delimiter till the next position of the delimiter.

```
string newString = "";
int position = m;
string delimeter = "|";
int start = IndexOfNth(str, delimeter , m);
if (start < 0)
    return;
int end = IndexOfNth(str.Substring(start + 1), delimeter, 1);

if (end < 0)
    newString = str.Substring(start);

newString = str.Substring(start, end + 1);


public static int IndexOfNth(string str, string value, int nth = 1) {
    if (nth <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("cannot be less than zero");
    int offset = str.IndexOf(value);
    for (int i = 1; i < nth; i++) {
        if (offset == -1) return -1;
        offset = str.IndexOf(value, offset + 1);
    }
    return offset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as phuzi, but as a function that could be in a C# utility class:

```
public static string GetSubString(string str, string delimiter, Int32 index)
        {
            if (str == null) return "";
            try
            {
                return str.Split(delimiter)[index];
            }
            catch
            {
                if (index == 0) return str;
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

Also see:  [Get the nth string of text between 2 separator characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503310/get-the-nth-string-of-text-between-2-separator-characters)